# Facebook locks down my account when I try to connect to it using Pidgin

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-apps, facebook-account

I use Pidgin with a plug-in called "Purple Facebook" to chat on Facebook. This way, I do not have to have a browser window open all the time only for chat. It's been working great, until recently when I try to connect to Facebook using Pidgin, it shows me an error message as follows:

```
User must verify their account on www.facebook.com (405)
```

Now, I got to Facebook website and log in, I am presented with a page that says**Your account is temporarily locked**, it further tells me that

```
We've locked your account because someone recently tried to log in from an unfamiliar location. Please help us to confirm that it was you who tried to log in.
```

When I continue, it asks me to verify whether it was actually me. Even if tell them that it was me, they persists on changing my password.
I change the password and recover my account. But this won't solve the issue with Pidgin. It still shows the same error.
I have already changed my password 5 times while trying to solve this, actually, Facebook force me to.
Does anyone here know what to do?